# iPad: Two NavigationControllers managing two ViewControllers at the same time

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview, navigationcontroller

Is it possible to have two NavigationControllers managing two TableViewControllers at the same time as illustrated below? If yes, how would you implement it in iOS? Thanks very much
[image: iPad View 1]

[image: iPad View 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how to use the new UIViewController containment APIs in iOS 5 to create your own container view controllers. Code available on Github: https://github.com/peterfriese/UIViewControllerContainmentSample

Answer (score 1):

In general, it can be done because people do it sometimes within a split view controller.  I think the implementation would be best done by having a container controller (similar in theory to a split view controller) that manages the screen space the way you've shown it.  It would then use child controllers, which in turn would be navigation controllers that contained table view controllers.